# How to build vue app with specified .env.devlopment file

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I have a vue.js app and I want to build it using .env.development file .

I am using this script in package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --mode=local",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "dev-build": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
},
```

When I run the script

```
npm run dev-build
```

It builds the file using .env.development but the build file size is too large nearly 15mb but when I run script

```
npm run build
```

It builds the file with .env.production and the size is reduced to 1mb .

How do I build the app using .env.development but creating build size that of production

Comment: It is not good practice mix one `.env.*` with another build option. If you have common options that should be in both cases, you can use the `.env` file

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes) defines the difference between the modes:

> `NODE_ENV=development` creates a webpack configuration which enables [HMR (Hot Module Replacement)](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/), doesn't hash assets or create vendor bundles in order to allow for fast re-builds when running a dev server.

So, **not creating** vendor bundles itself ends up with a larger result in your output. In short, there is no practical way of getting `development` as small as `production` -and it has some reasoning like responding to changes faster etc.